# Make an eBook out of a Website

Tags: ebook

Suppose that I find a interesting Website (having around 50 pages)
Suppose that I want to read it offline on my ebook device

How can i do it ?

I can download the website through HTTrack  and then
What tool to use to "pack" all downloaded pages into ONE ebook with a table of content ?

Comment: OT: lol I misread eMac instead of eBook, and wondered how could you convert a website to be a... computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best piece of software to do this (I think) is [Sigil](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/). Cross platform and open source.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how nice the code of the website is (and thus whether any changes need to be made to the CSS / HTML - ePub only supports a limited subset) a simple conversion could work using [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/). A simpler interface than Sigil, it can sometimes have problems with malformed (X)HTML.